# jQuery not populating text field until page refreshed in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I've got a form that uses jQuery to set the value of a text field.  The form doesn't work when the page is first loaded, but it does work after the refreshing the page  To help, describe the problem, I recorded a ~30 second video (hosted on SwfCabin):

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this?  I'm a jQuery newb and I've no clue!

Here's **jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".category").each(function () {
        $(this).find("a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var category = $(this).text();
            $("#post_categories").val(category);
        });
    });
});
```

And here's the **HTML form:**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" id="new_post"
method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="OCbmfFY1cNsaa5e+SbvcSrP0ubQTg432ECNGmvaU8bM="
        />
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="post_title">Title</label>
        <input id="post_title" name="post[title]" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="post_url">Url</label>
        <input id="post_url" name="post[url]" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="post_categories">Pick a category</label>
        <input type="text" id="post_categories" />
    </p>
    <p>Available choices:</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="category"> <a href="">programming</a>

        </li>
        <li class="category"> <a href="">cats</a>

        </li>
        <li class="category"> <a href="">batman</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: looks fine in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jmPg/1/

Comment: the jQuery can be simplified http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jmPg/3/  `jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".category a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).text();
        $("#post_categories").val(category);
    });
});`

Comment: also check your browser console for any errors that might have thrown

Comment: Can we see the whole page source? including footer/header.

Comment: Arun P Johny, your version of the code works great.  I just tried it.  Apparently it pays off to keep things simple.  I tweaked your version slightly to cater to my taste -- http://jsfiddle.net/4jmPg/4/.

Comment: CharliePrynn, I got the answer I was looking for.  But just in case it's be helpful to you, here's a gist w/ the full page source:  https://gist.github.com/amorphid/c0f32b40588c3eed711e

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine ,make sure you have included jQuery lib, also you can optimize the code a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.category a').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var category = $(this).text();
         $("#post_categories").val(category);
     });
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DGW3Q/

Comment: Farhan, thanks!  This work's great, too.  It optimization was the key to fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Arun P Johny and Farhan had provided the answer I was looking for, but it turns out I had a different problem.  The app I'm writing is Ruby on Rails and I didn't get the memo about how Rails' [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) overrides some jQuery functionality.

For example, by default in Rails 4.0.0, Turbolinks handles executing JavaScript on page load.  This means I was trying to use `$(document).ready(;`, but Turbolinks had hijacked that functionality.  For reasons I don't yet fully understand, refreshing re-enabled my jQuery script and then it started working.  I guess Turbolinks' version of `$(document).ready(;` doesn't get reset when the page is refreshed?

As a short term hack, I ended up solving the problem by installing the RubyGem "jquery-turbolinks".  At some point I'll need to learn how to use or disable Turbolinks.  Maybe I should just learn to use Angular or Ember :)  DOM shenanigans are a pain!

Ryan Bates discusses Turbolinks in [Episode #290 of Railscases](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks), including how code gets executed at page load.